# How do i set up dialogflow to read text off a webpage?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am simply asking if there is a way to have dialog flow read text off of a webpage and give answers based on said text? i am trying to get Disney world wait times to be read off of a google home mini

**site** : https://www.laughingplace.com/w/walt-disney-world/

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Have a look at Knowledge Base in DF.

Comment: ive tried with the knowledge base, but i cant seem to get any html docs to work with it

Comment: nor do i know how to get an answer out of that

Comment: Knowledge base is not perfect but that's the only way I know to achieve what you are looking for. Probably you should put some work to understand it better and then try it for your project.